# How to clear interval of clicked element

Tags: jquery

I am using http://www.antiyes.com/jquery-blink-plugin for blinking images on my document.

Code of that plugin is

```
(function($)
{
  $.fn.blink = function(options)
  {
     var defaults = { delay:500 };
     var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

     return this.each(function()
     {
        var obj = $(this);
        setInterval(function()
        {
            if($(obj).css("visibility") == "visible")
            {
                $(obj).css('visibility','hidden');
            }
            else
            {
                $(obj).css('visibility','visible');
            }
        }, options.delay);
    });
  }
}(jQuery))
```

**However I want to stop blinking of a particular image when I click on it.** Currently I am doing it by modifying the code as follows

```
    (function($) {
        $.fn.blink = function(options) {
            var defaults = { delay: 500, blinkClassName: 'blink' };
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() 
            {
                var obj = $(this);

                setInterval(function() 
                {
                    if ($(obj).attr('class').indexOf(options.blinkClassName) > -1) 
                    {
                        if ($(obj).css("visibility") == "visible")
                        {
                            $(obj).css('visibility', 'hidden');
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            $(obj).css('visibility', 'visible');
                        }
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        if ($(obj).css("visibility") != "visible") 
                        {
                            $(obj).css('visibility', 'visible');
                        }
                    }
                }, options.delay);
            });
        }
    } (jQuery))
```

I think there must be some better way to do it (perhaps using jquery data()) but unable to figure it out how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's `data` method is easy to use.  The key fact here is that `setInterval` returns a value.  This value is a number that identifies the interval.  You can supply this identifier to `clearInterval` to stop the interval occuring.

So your code will look something like this:

```
return this.each(function()
{
    var obj = $(this);
    var intervalID = setInterval(function()
    {
        var isVisible = obj.data('blink-visible');
        obj
           .css('visibility', isVisible ? 'hidden' : 'visible')
           .data('blink-visible', !isVisible);
    }, options.delay);
    obj.data('blink-interval', intervalID);
});
```

Then you could make a `stopBlink` method:

```
$.fn.stopBlink = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $el = $(this);
        var intervalID = $el.data('blink-interval');
        if (intervalID) {
            clearInterval(intervalID);
            $el.removeData('blink-interval');
            $el.css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
    });
};
```

---

Several other notes:

1. <s>`.css('visibility', 'visible')` is a verbose way of doing this.  You can use the `toggle` method: this hides the element if it is currently visible and shows it if it is hidden. This is what I have done above.</s>
2. You don't need to wrap `obj` in `$()`.  `obj` is already a jQuery selection (it was created with `$(this)`, so the extra wrap is entirely unnecessary.
3. Think very hard about using blink functionality. It is obtrusive and frequently annoying, and can have health consequences for people with epilepsy.

Comment: Hi lonesomeday...really very nice explaination. Thank you very much.

Comment: Its better to use CSS classes using .addClass instead of using .css (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336509/jquery-performance-css-or-addclass). the toggle() is worth a speed test also.

Comment: @yoav I meant to remove the `css` stuff -- I've edited my code and now it uses `toggle` throughout, with the boolean parameter handing the mandatory showing.

Comment: If I am not wrong toggle() modifies display property of an element and because of that whole page design breaks(in my case) but visibility only hides that element but it continue to occupy the space...therefore I used visibility property.

Comment: @cloudlight Ah, a good point. I have updated my answer with use of this CSS property.